# In go, how do you create an interface when methods are called by *Type?

Tags: types, go

Attempting to create an interface, but methods have `*Type`, not `Type` receivers

APOLOGIZE: was sleepy and mis-read error messages.  Thought I was being block from creating the DB interface when in reality I was mis-using it.  Sorry about that... will be more careful in the future!

```
type Char string

func (*Char) toType(v *string) interface{} {
        if v == nil {
                return (*Char)(nil)
        }
        var s string = *v
        ch := Char(s[0])
        return &ch
}
func (v *Char) toRaw() *string {
        if v == nil {
                return (*string)(nil)
        }
        s := *((*string)(v))
        return &s
}
```

from here I would like an interface that contains the methods `toType` and `toRaw`

```
type DB interface{
        toRaw() *string
        toType(*string) interface{}
}
```

does not work since the function receivers are pointers.  I say this because when I try to use it I get the error.k

```
    Char does not implement DB (toRaw method requires pointer receiver)
```

Is there a way to create an interface from `toType` and `toRaw`, or do I need to backup and have the receivers be the types themselves and not pointers to types?

Comment: Somehow it's difficult to get the idea behind your code. Please provide more infos.

Comment: trying to create DB interface using funcs `toRaw` and `toType`.  but cannot since the receivers to the funcs are pointers.  is there any way to declare a DB interface that incorporates `toRaw` and `toType`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what your problem is. Yes, the way you've written it, `*Char` conforms to the interface `DB` and `Char` doesn't. You can either

1. change your code so that the methods operate on the non-pointer type `Char` directly (which will automatically also work for `*Char` too)
2. only use `*Char` when you need something to be compatible with type `DB`

Comment: the problem is it appears I cannot make an interface with methods whose receivers are pointers.  is this true or is there some way around it?

Answer (score 5):

If you define your interface methods for the pointer type you must pass a pointer to the methods/functions expecting the interface.

Comment: "with an interface you should always be passing a pointer" This is not true. A non-pointer type can conform to an interface by implementing the necessary methods, just as easily as a pointer type.

Comment: That's not going to work. `c := &Char("foo")` is not a valid statement. You cannot take the address of `"foo"`.